# How to show that if a sequence of events converges, then the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ must converge to the same limit?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to show that if the limit of $Z_n$ converges to $Z$, where $Z_n$ is defined to be a general sequence of events, that the $\limsup Z_n$  and $\liminf Z_n$ must equal to $Z$ as well. My approach is the following, first define as follows:

\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} Z_n &= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\bigcup_{j=n}^{\infty} Z_j\right)\\\
\liminf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} Z_n &= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\bigcap_{j=n}^{\infty} Z_j\right).
\end{align*}

Then show that $\liminf Z_n \subset \limsup Z_n$, which is trivial and holds under any case. Then, I would like to show that $\limsup Z_n \subset \liminf Z_n$. However, I am having trouble here as I am not sure how to use the fact that the limit converges. From the definition, the convergence means that for each $\omega \in \Omega$, there will exist an $N$ such that it is either the case that $\omega \in Z_n$ for $N\geq n$ or $\omega \notin Z_n$ for $N\geq n$. It seems to me that the right path would involve using the fact that the $Z_n$ eventually reach $Z$ and use that to change something in the limsup and liminf definitions. Would anyone have any idea if this approach is in the right direction?

Comment: Usually $Z_n \to Z$ is defined to mean $\liminf_n Z_n = \limsup_n Z_n$.

Comment: So are you saying that there doesnt exist a proof?

Comment: user, @David is saying that for him it is true _by definition_. Perhaps you should edit your question to make the definition _you're_ using stand out more instead of hiding it in the middle of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** In order to show that $\limsup Z_n\subseteq \liminf Z_n$ you assume that $\omega\in\limsup Z_n$ for some $\omega$ and seek to show that this same $\omega$ is also in $\liminf Z_n$.

Because you're also assuming that your definition of convergence is true about the $Z_n$s, you also know that there is an $N$ such that $\omega$ is either in *all* $Z_n$ for $n\ge N$ or in *none* of them (note that the inequalities in the definition you're quoting are the wrong way around). Which of these can be the case if $\omega\in\limsup Z_n$?